# Is there any way to show the records in view mode when clicking the edit when it has fully billed status in Netsuite Suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

function beforeLoad(context){
var Type = context.type;if(Type== context.UserEventType.EDIT && Status=='fullyBilled'){
var form = context.form;
return redirectUrl = url.resolveRecord({
recordType: 'purchaseorder',
isEditMode: false
});
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [redirect.toRecord(options)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4424995667.html) from the [N/redirect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4424286105.html) module.

```js
define(['N/redirect'], function(redirect) {

  function beforeLoad(context) {
    var newRecord = context.newRecord
    var type = context.type
    if (type != context.UserEventType.EDIT) return

    var status = newRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'status' })
    if (status != "fullyBilled") return

    redirect.toRecord({
      type: newRecord.type,
      id: newRecord.id,
      isEditMode: false
    })
  }

  return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad
  }

})
```